# Nautilus remote mount resolve numeric uids and gids to names

Tags: ubuntu, user-accounts, nautilus

In Gnome Nautilus I have a remote samba mount through SSH under Ubuntu 10.04 (gvfs).
When I check any file properties it displays the user and group as numeric. Is there a way
to make it get the names of the user and groups ?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a nautilus problem, this is a *nix problem. Your system does not know the remote system's UIDs and GIDs, and as such cannot resolve them. The way to fix this is to have the two systems use a common auth database, such as one provided by LDAP.

Comment: Or in the case of Samba - `winbindd`.